# How to retrieve checkboxes values in jQuery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Trying to post a question for the accepted answer to #786142
If you edit this solution and change the textarea tag to any other block level element(with the same id attribute) it no longer works. In my case I am trying to remove a php gd-rotated image returned by an Ajax call (clicking the checkbox) when the user changes their mind and unchecks that same checkbox. I realize val() is not the function to append html data, but I need to find out how to make this function work with a ul list; then I will work out how to deal with the image itself. Appreciate any answers you all might have.

Here's one that works. (see the example)

```
function updateTextArea() {         
    var allVals = [];
    $('#c_b :checked').each(function() {
      allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#t').val(allVals)
 }
$(function() {
  $('#c_b input').click(updateTextArea);
  updateTextArea();
});
```

Some number of months later another question was asked in regards to how to keep the above working if the ID changes. Well, the solution boils down to mapping the updateTextArea function into something generic that uses classes, and to use the live function to monitor the DOM for those changes. Sorry, I'm not really up to writing the example at the moment.

Comment: @user , you can use class names right??

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question.
So if you have an ul list like this:

```
<ul id="test_ul"><li></li></ul>
```

and you would like to update this, instead of a textarea element, than you could modify your code like this:

```
function updateUlLi(ul_id) {
    var allVals = [];
    $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        allVals.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('#'+ul_id).html('<li>'+allVals+'</li>');
}

$(function() {
    updateUlLi('test_ul');
    $('#c_b input').click(function(){
        updateUlLi('test_ul');
    });
});
```

It collects all checked checkboxes (!) on your site, not just the ones that are in an "id-given" element.
Another modification: you pass the ul's id to the function.
Hope that helps.